# C# display components based on name

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox, components

Is it possible to set a components visible attribute based on its name?
I have 12 "master" components (comboboxes) if you want to call them that and based on the selection in these I want to display anywhere from 1 to 16 textboxes. These are named in numeric order such as combobox1_textbox_0, combobox1_textbox_1 and so on. What I would like to do ideally is take the index of the combobox and pass it as a parameter to a method that sets the textboxes visible attribute to visible/hidden depending on the index passed into the method.

Is this possible? in pseudocode or what you call it I would like it to work something like this:

```
    private void methodToSetVisibleAttribute(int indexFromMainComboBox)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if(i < index)
            {
                combobox1_textbox_+i.Visible = true;                
            }
            else
            { 
                combobox1_textbox_+i.Visible = false; 
            }
        }
    }
```

I could do panels or something for the choices but seeing as all the selections from the combobox will use the same textboxes but in different amounts it seems like alot of work to make a panel for every possible selection not to mention difficult to expand the program later on.

Comment: yea forgot to mention that, its winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and not WPF, you can use [`ControlCollection.Find()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find controls by name:

```
var textBox = this.Controls.Find(string.Format("combobox1_textbox_{0}", i), true).OfType<ComboBox>().FirstOrDefault();
if (textBox != null)
    textBox.Visible = (i < index);
else
    Debug.Assert(false, "textbox not found"); // Or throw an exception if you prefer.
```

Comment: Thanks, went with this one, worked just perfect, saved me atleast a few hundred lines of code sofar and probably alot more  to come aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest an alternative to your approach, maybe not quite what you're looking for:

Place your combo boxes in a `List<ComboBox>` and you can access them by an index number.

```
List<ComboBox> myCombos = new List<ComboBox>();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
  ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
  //do what ever you need to do here.  Set its location, add items, etc.
  Form1.Controls.Add(cb); //Alternatively add it to another container.
  myCombos.Add(cb); //Now it's in a list.
}
```

Modify them like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if(i < index)
        {
            myCombos[i].Visible = true;                
        }
        else
        { 
            myCombos[i].Visible = false; 
        }
    }
```

Or even more succintly:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
      myCombos[i].Visible = i < index;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like a smart solution but manually having to place the controls and fill them with items (or make them databound) every time is a little more timeconsuming then the other answer